# Awk match multiple strings and print both fields on the same line

Tags: awk

I have an input file that does not have a consistent structure for the fields. What I'm trying to do is find the correct two fields and print their content on the same line.

EDIT: 
Here is a potential example for the input file:

```
abc=012 aaa=000 cba=210 bbb=111
aaa=555 abc=567 cba=765 bbb=666
aaa=444 abc=456 bbb=555 cba=654
```

This program almost works

```
  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /aaa/) {print $i}}}' file
  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /bbb/) {print $i}}}' file
```

However, this prints everything on a new field, and it does not display the data correctly either:

```
aaa=000
aaa=555
aaa=444
bbb=111
bbb=666
bbb=555
```

What I need is for the field aaa to follow the field bbb on the same line, like this:

```
aaa=000 bbb=111
aaa=555 bbb=666
aaa=444 bbb=555
```

How can this be done?

Comment: how one should define that the 2 fields are correct?

Comment: if they match 'aaa' or 'bbb' respectively. I'dd edit the question to include an example of the input file.

Comment: what if there would be line `ccc` between `aaa` and `bbb`?

Comment: I edited the question. Hopefully that is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is `awk`, using `match()` and `substr()` function, modify `search="..."` variable according to your need, the order you input the same way it will give you result.

```
awk -v search="aaa,bbb" '
BEGIN{
    n=split(search, arr, /,/) 
}
{
    for(i=1; i in arr; i++)
          printf("%s%s", (match($0,"(^| )"arr[i]"=[^ ]*") ? substr($0,(RSTART>1?RSTART+1:RSTART),(RSTART>1?RLENGTH-1:RLENGTH)) : ""), i==n ? ORS : OFS)      
}' infile
```

**Test Results:**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat infile
abc=012 aaa=000 cba=210 bbb=111
aaa=555 abc=567 cba=765 bbb=666
aaa=444 abc=456 bbb=555 cba=654

akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk -v search="aaa,bbb" '
BEGIN{
    n=split(search, arr, /,/) 
}
{
    for(i=1; i in arr; i++)
          printf("%s%s", (match($0,"(^| )"arr[i]"=[^ ]*") ? substr($0,(RSTART>1?RSTART+1:RSTART),(RSTART>1?RLENGTH-1:RLENGTH)) : ""), i==n ? ORS : OFS)      
}' infile
aaa=000 bbb=111
aaa=555 bbb=666
aaa=444 bbb=555
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -v search="aaa,bbb" '             # call awk set variable search
BEGIN{

    # split string in variable search
    # into array, separated by comma
    # arr[1]  will have aaa
    # arr[2]  will have bbb
    # variable n will have 2, which is count of array

    n=split(search, arr, /,/) 
}
{
    # loop through array arr
    for(i=1; i in arr; i++)
    {
         found = 0                   # default state

         # if there is match
         # beginning or space followed by your word
         # = anything except space char
         # which creates regexp like : 
         #    /(^| )aaa=[^ ]*/
         #    /(^| )bbb=[^ ]*/
         # if matches then 

         if(match($0,"(^| )"arr[i]"=[^ ]*")){ 

             # if it was not beginning then there will be space char
             # lets increment starting position and decrement length
             if(RSTART>1){
               RSTART++              # we got space so one char +
               RLENGTH--             # lenght one char -
             }
            found =1                 # found flag
         }

         # ternary operator syntax : ( your_condition ) ? true_action : false_action 
         # if found is true then use substr
         # else ""
         # if i equal n then print output row separator else output field separaor
         printf("%s%s", ( found ? substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) : ""), i==n ? ORS : OFS)
    }      
}' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^(aaa|bbb)=/){ printf "%s%s",(!c++? "":FS),$i  }; 
       print ""; c=0 }' file
```

---

Or with short GNU **awk** (assuming that `aaa` is always goes first):

```
awk 'match($0,/(aaa=[0-9]+).* (bbb=[0-9]+)/,a){ print a[1],a[2] }' file
```

The output for both approaches:

```
aaa=000 bbb=111
aaa=555 bbb=666
aaa=444 bbb=555
```

Answer (score 1):

using GNU **awk** with multi char record separator

This will work even if `bbb` comes before `aaa` in the string

```
$ awk -v RS="[ \n]" '/aaa|bbb/{ printf $1 (i++%2==0? " " : ORS) }' file
```

Output:

```
aaa=000 bbb=111
aaa=555 bbb=666
aaa=444 bbb=555
```

`-v RS="[ \n]"` : Set space  and `\n` as the record separator

`/aaa|bbb/{ printf $1 (i++%2==0? " " : ORS) }` : If field contains `aaa` or `bbb` then print it. If `i++%2==0` then print append  else append `\n`